# Start next thread loop vs Break current loop vs Break current loop in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In Flow Control and Result Status Action Handler, there are 3 similar statement:

Start next thread loop
Break current loop
Go to the next iteration of Current loop

I can not understand difference of these statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Start next thread loop` just starts the next iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).

   [image]
2. `Break current loop` and `Go to the next iteration of Current loop` are rather more applicable to [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) or [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) where you have "nested loops"

   - `Break current loop`

     [image]
   - `Go to the next iteration of Current loop`

     [image]

Comment: My friend Dimitri so thanks, I would have had a hard time without your help.